# How can I detect during file upload if the file has moved or been deleted?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, firefox

I have an ASP.NET MVC web page that has a file upload control.  Under rare conditions the file referenced by the user moves or is deleted on the filesystem prior to the user triggering the post to the page.  In IE9 the page successfully posts but the ContentLength is zero (expected) and can be handled server-side.  However in Firefox I find that the POST action never reaches the server.

Is there anyway to detect that the file reference is still valid prior to posting the page?  Or a way to detect that an error occurred client-side during the POST due to the moved/deleted file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just input type="file", you have no access to check whether the file actually exists until an upload attempt is made. There are some emerging functionalities like [FileReader](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) which may help as browsers mature (as it's not available in all browsers) that should make the upload process far smoother (and will make detection of this situation more simple).

If you use an Ajax style upload process, you could initiate the upload right away to help prevent the issue from occurring in the first place.

Or, a bit hacky: one idea for Firefox would be to add a setTimeout in the onsubmit event that fires after a second ... and checks to see if the upload started (by querying the server using Ajax to a JsonResult action/function that can quickly see if an upload started, etc.). It's a bit messy though as you'll need to worry about timing issues -- and may be overkill just to handle the cases where this is occurring.